# Working on a program that takes items to make a shopping list. I must store them as variables item1,item2,item3 and output each item separately

Tags: javascript, prompt, pseudocode, template-literals

**Is there a way to reduce the number of prompts to one line of code, perhaps a prompt that allows for a multi-line input box when prompted in the format of a list? Any feedback is much appreciated.**

```
let nameUser=prompt("What is your name?");//Request user to input their name

let item1=prompt("What is item 1 on your shopping list?");//Request user to input the first item on their shopping list
let item2=prompt("What is item 2 on your shopping list?");//Request user to input the second item on their shopping list
let item3=prompt("What is item 3 on your shopping list?");//Request user to input the third item on their shopping list

console.log(`${nameUser}'s shopping list:
${item1}
${item2}
${item3}
`);//Print users shopping list with template literals
```

I have tried to store the items as an array and split them but that doesn't help.

Comment: If you are after a popout style for multiline a [dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) could be of use. Needs more setup. Otherwise code looks fine, minus the values checks and such. More often than not the oneliner solutions are not that good as someone would think.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a forloop

```
let nameUser=prompt("What is your name?");//Request user to input their name

let items = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    items[i] = prompt(`What is item ${i+1} on your shopping list?`);
}


console.log(`${nameUser}'s shopping list: \n${items.join('\n')}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
let nameUser=prompt("What is your name?");
let obj = {}
for(let i=1;i<=3;i++){
    obj[`item${i}`]=prompt(`What is item ${i} on your shopping list?`);
 }
 const {item1,item2,item3}=obj
 console.log(`${nameUser}'s shopping list:
 ${item1}
 ${item2}
 ${item3}
 `);
```